# Listing entity fields

Tags: 7, entities

I wonder if there is a good, and easy way to get all fields of an entity.

I have a taxonomy vocabulary. Its terms have a special field I want to make list in a select box in one of my modules, so that users can select a special value of the term. Therefore, I need a way to list the possible fields for this term.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The function you are looking for is [field_info_instances()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7).

> Retrieves information about field instances.

Answer (score 4):

**Drupal 7**

You may try:

```
  $info = entity_get_property_info($entity_type);
  $info += array(
    'properties' => array(),
    'bundles' => array(),
  );
  // Add all bundle properties.
  foreach ($info['bundles'] as $bundle => $bundle_info) {
    $bundle_info += array('properties' => array());
    $info['properties'] += $bundle_info['properties'];
  }
  var_dump($info['properties']);
```

Or if you have [Entity](http://drupal.org/project/entity) module installed, then try:

```
entity_get_all_property_info('node');
```

Drush commands (one of these):

```
drush eval "var_dump(entity_get_all_property_info('node'));"
drush eval "print var_export(array_keys(entity_get_all_property_info('node')));"
```

Answer (score 2):

Can also use the function : [field_info_field_map()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_field_map/7)

In place of returning entities going down to fields, it starts from field and go down to entities. That second one is fine to see where fields are going, whereas *field_info_instances()* shows how entities are built.