# List fields for a content-type?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Listing entity fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14352/listing-entity-fields)

Is there a function or technique anywhere in the Drupal API to list fields for a particular content type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About list your fields for your content type, I guess that you can use `node--NAMECONTENTTYPE.tpl.php` in your directory template.

to be more detailed, you can copy/paste to your theme directory the file node.tpl.php (located in `modules > node` or already located inside your theme directory) and rename it according your content type. for example, if the Content Type is `Article` the name will be `node--article.tpl.php`

already inside in `node--article.tpl.php` you can list the fields with the variable `$content` using `print_r($content);` to see the list of the fields that you can use to your node (or if you use [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel), is best use `dsm($content);`)

**to call each field you can use:**

for example I have a field called `field_demotext1`, then:

```
print render($content['field_demotext1']);
```

here is the example of zone in the `node--article.tpl.php` using `dsm($content);` to print list of fileds:

```
  <div class="content clearfix"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php
      hide($content['comments']);
      hide($content['links']);
      print render($content);
      dsm($content);
    ?>
  </div>
```