# How can I use field_attach_load()

Tags: 7, entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Listing entity fields](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14352/listing-entity-fields)

I want list fields of my content type(example: blog), so as described at [Drupal API reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_load/7), I should pass $entity_type and $entities to this function.

I know $entity_type is 'node', but how can I fill $entities?
I should fill $entities with bundle of "blog" so I should know the bundle ID.
How can I know bundle ID for blog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the list of fields per content type (now bundles in Drupal 7), you should use [`field_info_instances()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7).

```
//List all fields of bundle "your_content_type" using devel module
dsm(field_info_instances('node', 'your_content_type'));
```